# how to change color of matrix bracket

Tags: color, matrices

How can I change the color of bracket in following matrix.

```
\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0.5 \end{bmatrix}
```

I want entries in black while [ ] in red.
Is it possible to do it using bmatrix

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here I provide `bmatrixcolor` with an optional argument for the color.  EDITED to save the pre-existing color, rather than returning to `black`, using the `xcolor` feature `.` to refer to the current color.  In this way, the matrix data will be set in the prevailing color.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,xcolor}
\newenvironment{bmatrixcolor}[1][red]
  {\colorlet{savethecolor}{.}\colorlet{bracecolor}{#1}%
    \color{bracecolor}\left[\color{savethecolor}\begin{matrix}}
  {\end{matrix}\color{bracecolor}\right]}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0.5 \end{bmatrix}
\]
\[
\begin{bmatrixcolor} 1 & 0.5 \end{bmatrixcolor}
\]
\[
\begin{bmatrixcolor}[blue] 1 & 0.5 \end{bmatrixcolor}
\]
\color{red}
\[
x =\begin{bmatrixcolor}[blue] 1 & 0.5 \end{bmatrixcolor}\!^T
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You saved me an answer. The last color setting is not necessary, though.

Answer (score 1):

The package `nicematrix` provides in the version 5.7 (2020-11-23) a key `delimiters-color` for the color of the delimiters in its environments (similar to the environments of `amsmath`).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}


$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 \\
3 & 4
\end{bmatrix}$\qquad
$\begin{bNiceMatrix}[delimiters-color=red] 
1 & 2 \\
3 & 4
\end{bNiceMatrix}$

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]