# Change color of matrix brackets

Tags: color, matrices

I want to be able to change the color of a matrix brackets. I have found [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/329552/how-to-change-color-of-matrix-bracket) but it is not exactly what I am looking for, since with this answer the subindex just right outside the matrix is not at the desired height. I would like to be able to write something similar to

```
\begin{equation*}
   \begin{pmatrix}
        1 \\
        2 \\
        -1
   \end{pmatrix}_{\!\!e}
\end{equation*}
```

and obtain

[image]

but with a different color for the brackets (and maybe also a different color for the subindex).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to change color of matrix bracket](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/329552/how-to-change-color-of-matrix-bracket)

Comment: @SachchidanandPrasad -- The OP mentioned, that that answer messes with the positioning of the subscript

Comment: @SachchidanandPrasad It does not. As I mention in the post, I had already seen this answer, but it messes with the positioning of the subscript, as #DG' says.

Comment: @Just_a_newbie Yeah just saw that, sorry for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,xcolor,environ}

\NewEnviron{pmatrixcolor}[1][red]{%
  \colorlet{currentcolor}{.}%
  \mathinner{\begingroup\color{#1}\left(\color{currentcolor}%
    \begin{matrix}
      \BODY
    \end{matrix} \color{#1}\right)\endgroup}}

\begin{document}
\[
    \begin{pmatrix}
        1 \\
        2 \\
        -1
    \end{pmatrix}
    _e
\]

\[
    \begin{pmatrixcolor}
        1 \\
        2 \\
        -1
    \end{pmatrixcolor}
    _e
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

The environment `{pNiceMatrix}` of `nicematrix` has a key `delimiters/color` for the color of the delimiters.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}
\[
    \begin{pmatrix}
        1 \\
        2 \\
        -1
    \end{pmatrix}
    _e
\]

\[
    \begin{pNiceMatrix}[delimiters/color=red]
        1 \\
        2 \\
        -1
    \end{pNiceMatrix}
    _e
\]
\end{document}
```

[image: Ouput of the above code]